# How to calculate R squared on monthly frequency for daily data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Currently I calculate the R squared for the whole dataset and for monthly R squared I slice the dataframe into smaller dataframes with the corresponding month and this is really unwieldy for a large dataset. Is there a way to easy calculate R squared for each month?

I use this for the whole dataset:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_true = df['no2']
y_pred = df['temp']
r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

Dataset:

```
date,no2,temp
2022-03-27,22.0,12.0
2022-03-28,21.0,11.0
2022-03-29,25.0,15.0
2022-03-30,29.0,12.0
2022-03-31,24.0,17.0
2022-04-21,34.0,16.0
2022-04-22,32.0,19.0
2022-04-23,38.0,18.0
2022-04-24,37.0,19.0
2022-04-25,32.0,20.0
2022-05-25,36.0,21.0
2022-05-26,34.0,23.0
2022-05-27,39.0,21.0
2022-05-28,33.0,24.0
2022-05-29,31.0,22.0
2022-05-30,30.0,26.0
```

What I want:

```
date,r_squared
2022-03,45
2022-04,42
2022-05,56
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I did a pre-processing step which may or may not be necessary for you. I converted the date column from object to datetime. (You can check df.dtypes to see if this step is necessary.)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Next, I group the dataframe by month, using `pd.Grouper()` to select the grouping duration. For each group, I apply the correlation function you mention.

```
correlation = df.set_index('date') \
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')) \
    .apply(lambda month_df: r2_score(month_df['no2'], month_df['temp']))
```

The previous step resulted in a Series, and you want a DataFrame. The next step is to convert that Series into a DataFrame with the desired column name.

```
correlation = pd.DataFrame(correlation, columns=['r_squared'])
```

Output:

```
            r_squared
date                 
2022-03-01 -15.443299
2022-04-01 -42.621795
2022-05-01 -14.465046
```

Comment: What I don't understand is, how does groupby calculate the r², does it take the month average and calculate it? Because when I calculate r² with the sliced dataframe for august in my dataset it gives me r²: 78 and with your method I get 68. When I check it in Tableau it shows me that 78 is right for august in my dataset.

Comment: @Gobrel It's defined by taking each month separately, taking the column values for that month, and calculating correlation for them. `when I calculate r² with the sliced dataframe for august in my dataset it gives me r²: 78` How are you calculating R^2, then? I've never heard of a method which can give you numbers larger than 1.

Comment: My error, I meant 0.78. I sliced the dataframe where I have one dataframe for each month. When I use your solution for the original dataframe I got 0.68 and with the sliced dataframe I got 0.78, Tableau also gave me 0.78.

Comment: @Gobrel So, there are a couple of ways you can define R^2. One way you can define it is to say it's the square of the correlation coefficient, after fitting a linear regression. This is not what sklearn does. sklearn defines it as (1 - RSS/TSS), without fitting a linear regression from y_pred to y_true first. The assumption is that you've already built a model which predicts y_true, and you want to evaluate it versus some other linear regression model. e.g. `r2_score([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6])` evaluates to -6, despite being perfectly correlated.

Comment: I assumed you wanted the sklearn definition based on the code in your question, but maybe that is not the case? You can read more about how sklearn defines it here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

Comment: What confuses me is that I get 0.68 with your solution where I put the same two colums in `r2_score(df[col1], df[col2]` I did like in the sliced month dataframe where I get 0.78. I will double check it to spot mistakes.